# Turning a JSON data to a GeoJSON data. For Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, mapbox, json

I am new to programming. I took a few crash courses and know the basic structure of JSON data.
Working with leafletjs to implement a choloropeth map.

I am required to convert my own data which in JSON format

```js
[{

    "UP": {

        "name": "Uttar Pradesh",
        "capital": {
            "name": "Lucknow",
            "details": [{
                "name": "Lucknow",
                "coordinates": [26.846511, 80.946683],
                "population": "2,901,474",
                "sexratio": 915,
                "literacy": 84.72
            }]
        },
        "population": "199,812,341",
        "growth": 20.23,
        "area": 240928,
        "density": 829,
        "sexratio": 912,
        "literacy": 67.68

    },

    "MH": {

        "name": "Maharashtra",
        "capital": {
            "name": "Mumbai",
            "details": [{
                "name": "Mumbai",
                "coordinates": [19.075984, 72.877656],
                "population": "18,414,288",
                "sexratio": 852,
                "literacy": 90.28
            }]
        },
        "population": "112,374,333",
        "growth": 15.99,
        "area": 307713,
        "density": 365,
        "sexratio": 929,
        "literacy": 82.34

    },
    }]
```

To GeoJSON format which looks something like this

```js
var states={"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[

    {"type":"Feature","id":"01","properties":
        {"name":"Alabama","density":94.65},"geometry":
          {"type":"Polygon","coordinates": 
           [[[-87.359296,35.00118],[-85.606675,34.984749],[-85.431413,34.124869],[-85.184951,32.859696], 
           [-85.069935,32.580372],[-84.960397,32.421541],[-85.004212,32.322956],[-84.889196,32.262709], 
           [-85.058981,32.13674],[-85.053504,32.01077],[-85.141136,31.840985],[-85.042551,31.539753], 
           [-85.113751,31.27686],[-85.004212,31.003013],[-85.497137,30.997536],[-87.600282,30.997536], 
           [-87.633143,30.86609],[-87.408589,30.674397],[-87.446927,30.510088],[-87.37025,30.427934], 
           [-87.518128,30.280057],[-87.655051,30.247195],[-87.90699,30.411504],[-87.934375,30.657966], 
           [-88.011052,30.685351],[-88.10416,30.499135],[-88.137022,30.318396],[-88.394438,30.367688], 
           [-88.471115,31.895754],[-88.241084,33.796253],[-88.098683,34.891641],[-88.202745,34.995703], 
           [-87.359296,35.00118]]]}}};
```

I don't get the format of GeoJSON.
It says

> geometry missing.

I have tried several JSON to GeoJSON converters online. Doesn't seem to be working.

Can someone show me just one example how to convert my JSON data to GeoJSON? 
How to do that?
What are features? I don't understand.

Comment: You don't have coordinates for the states. Thus you cannot make a choropleth map with your data. You can make a circle map because you have coordinates of the capitals.

Comment: @Stefan I understand that. I can fill in the co-ordinates later.  I have the co-ordinates in an another file that is in GeoJSON format. I want to add these fields like density,population,capital (that i am having as JSON array of objects)to that file.

Comment: did you look at the spec? https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946

Comment: @IanTurton Thank you for the reference.

Comment: @IanTurton Thank you for the reference.
So,I am supposed to have a "FeatureCollection" for every array of data.
Which has members the following members:

1. {"type":"feature",

2."geometry": {
       2.a

    "type": "Point",
       2.b 
    "coordinates":[long,latitudes]
},

3."properties":{
   "property one":"value one",
   "property two":"value two",
   "property three:":{ 
             "sub property one":"value",
             "sub property one":"value",
 }
}
} //end of object 1 and so on. I think i got it. Am i correct here in understanding?

Comment: I don't see a need for converting the JSON to a GeoJSON. I think I would first open your GeoJSON file with the states. Then, when I visualize the GeoJSON, I would simply retrieve the attributes from the JSON.